# AJAX call PHP file containing SendGrid email

Tags: php, ajax, azure, sendgrid

I would like to send an email on a button click and have the service set up with Azure.

**productPage.php**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'outbidEmail.php',
                            data: {},
                            type: 'post',
                            success:function(output) {
                                alert ("email sent");
                            }
                        });
});
```

**outbidEmail.php**

```
<?php

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/';
 $user = 'username removed';
 $pass = 'password removed';

$to = 'abc@hotmail.com';

$subject = "Auction Website: You have been outbidded!";
$message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>You have been outbidded!</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Heljko</p>
</body>
</html>
";

 $params = array(
      'api_user' => $user,
      'api_key' => $pass,
      'to' => $email_address,
      'subject' => $subject,
      'html' => $message,
      'text' => 'testing body',
      'from' => 'noreply@ajewfheuwfh.com',
   );

 $request = $url.'api/mail.send.json';

 // Generate curl request
 $session = curl_init($request);

 // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);

 // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
 curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

 // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
 curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

 // obtain response
 $response = curl_exec($session);
 curl_close($session);

 // print everything out
 print_r($response);

?>
```

The ajax function is called when a button is clicked - the alert "email sent" displays. However, no email is being received. However, this isn't likely to be an issue with the user or password as we have received emails elsewhere for our application (but using a  instead).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add the following line to stop cURL from verifying the peer's certificate:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```